# Coding Bat issue (Python warm-up 2:string_splosion)

Tags: python

Can anyone help me figure out the following error with the below code for Python warm-up 2, string_splosion?:

Error: name 'empty' is not defined

Code:

```
def string_splosion(str):
  empty = ''
  lenS= 1
  for i in range(0, lenS, 1):
    empty = empty + i
    lenS = lenS +1
return empty
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: For what I can tell from the code you pasted your returned statement is outside of your method and empty is not defined outside your method hence the "empty" not defined error. IE you need to indent your return statement.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian Forsius stated, you need to have the rerun statement indented within your function. As it was, `empty` was only defined within your function, not in the outer scope.

```
   def string_splosion(str):
      empty = ''
      lenS= 1
      for i in range(0, lenS, 1):
        empty = empty + i
        lenS = lenS +1
      return empty
```